# Good description of Calculus of Inductive Construction

Tags: lo.logic, dependent-type

I want to learn more about Calculus of Inductive Constructions. What can you recommend to read on this topic? All the materials which I found are either in French or too basic (the Coq'Art book).

The thing I am interested the most are not definitions but the proofs of important properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which properties you're after, but what about the original paper:

Thierry Coquand, Gérard P. Huet: The Calculus of Constructions. Inf. Comput. 76(2/3): 95-120 (1988)

I got it from: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0890540188900053#

Comment: He is asking about the Calculus of Inductive Constructions, not the plain Calculus of Constructions. The former is an extension of the latter. A good reference may be this:
Th. Coquand and C. Paulin-Mohring. Inductively defined types. In P. Martin-Löf and G. Mints, editors, Proceedings of Colog’88, volume 417 of Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Sprin­ger-Verlag, 1990.

Comment: @JanJohannsen The problem with it is that it isn't freely available.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Jan - btw parts of the paper are available on [Google books](http://books.google.at/books?id=o_f4UwiZtL0C)

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov, did you end up finding "Inductively defined types" online? If you hit this problem, you can often ask for a draft from one of the authors.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the Coq user manual, in particular [this section](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/language/cic.html) is pretty nice (the server seems to be down at the moment though).

For meta-theory you can try some recent work of Benjamin Werner *et al.*, see [Proof-irrelevant model of CC with predicative induction and judgmental equality](http://www.lmcs-online.org/ojs/viewarticle.php?id=675)
 and [On the strength of proof-irrelevant type theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3928) for the most salient work.